# What to do about this warning from icloud.com

Tags: icloud, safari

I have logged in to icloud.com via Safari and created a new directory somewhere in the iCloud drive and uploaded a small file into the new directory. Then I made the file sharable via the appropriate button on icloud.com, copied the link provided and verified that the link works. Then, when I tried to log out of icloud.com by clicking on the Sign Out option that appeared when I clicked on the small image of mine at the top right of the icloud webpage, I got the following error message, presumably from icloud.com:

[image]

Then I clicked on Cancel and decided to wait a bit. I have waited for nearly ten minutes but the error message reappears whenever I try to log out of the icloud webpage, i.e. icloud.com.

Should I worry about this warning at all, i.e. would it affect the iCloud link I just created (which still works), or just ignore it and complete the signing out of icloud.com? Recreating a link is of course no big deal but I have already sent the link I created to another party and I do not want to keep sending new links.

This is all happening under macOS 13.5.2 installed on a 2019 MacBook Pro. I am signed into iCloud on the MBP and, should it be necessary, below is a screenshot of my overall iCloud settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After waiting another half an hour after posting my question, I have decided that I would most probably close the icloud.com tab in Safari accidentally myself eventually.

So just to see what else I might be able to do to solve the issue, I opened another tab in Safari, and typed icloud.com in the address bar. I was automatically logged in to icloud.com in the new tab as I expected. Then, I clicked on the Sign Out option in the new icloud.com tab and that signed me out right away without a warning. I then also closed the original icloud.com tab. When I checked the link I had shared, it was still working at the end!

I am not sure if opening a second tab and using it to log out of icloud.com actually helped resolve any real issues but this is what has happened in case anyone else faces a similar warning from icloud.com after uploading a file and then creating a shareable link.

I also want to say I was quite surprised by the warning message because once a file upload is completed or a sharable link is created, there should be nothing expected of me or the browser on my computer by icloud.com, but the warning message implied that there was. I hope it won't happen again.